# Does anyone know where to get RxSwift Pod for xcode 10 and swift 4.2?

Tags: xcode, rx-swift

I tried a couple of variations in podfile to no avail...I assumed it was pod 'RxSwft', '-> 4.2' but get an error that is less than descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

[image]

[image]

[image]

maybe you have another problem, can you add the error description?

And also I would recommend to always follow the [page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) documentation:

[image]

there it still says to use 4.0, and even when i used in my podfile 4.0 it still installed (4.2.0) and i use the Xcode 10 beta, working fine.